# My ListView is still slow after using ViewHolder

Tags: android, listview

I'm using listview with customized list item layout.Also i'm using ViewHolder on my list view but the performance of list view is still very slow.How to solve this?

Here is my Activity.java

```
public class FilemanagerActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView list;
    private TextView status;
    private String[] list_items;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_filemanager);

        //Initialization
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

///Function to List a dirs from that dir
        listFiles("/");     
        list.setItemsCanFocus(false);

        CustomAdapter adapter=new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list_filemanager, list_items);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {     
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.filemanager, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // CustomAdapter
    private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        String[] values;
        int layout,img_dir;

        LayoutInflater lf;

        public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, String[] objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            values = objects;
            layout = resource;          
            lf= getLayoutInflater();
            img_dir=R.drawable.device_mobile;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder viewholder;

            if(convertView==null)
            {
                convertView = lf.inflate(layout, parent, false);            
                viewholder=new ViewHolder();
                viewholder.checkbox=(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_checkbox);
                viewholder.txt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_txt);
                //viewholder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_img);
                convertView.setTag(viewholder);
            }
            else
            {
                viewholder=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }


            viewholder.txt.setText(values[position]);
            //viewholder.img.setImageResource(img_dir);
            viewholder.checkbox.setChecked(true);           
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    //View Holder
    public class ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView txt;
        public ImageView img;
        public CheckBox checkbox;       
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"    
    tools:context=".FilemanagerActivity" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/list"   
        android:focusable="false"                    
        ></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

List item Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"    
>        
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"                     
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:id="@+id/list_txt"                
        android:layout_weight="0.2"        
        />
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/list_checkbox"        
        android:layout_weight="0.8"       
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Is there any performance error in my code?

Comment: Your code seems Ok, are you trying it on a real device or emulator?

Comment: I'm testing it on my android device.(Xolo q700)

Comment: Use Traceview and determine where your time is being spent.

Comment: your weights are weird. you probably should use layout_width="0dp" with those weights.

Comment: you should specify android:weightsum inside your linearlayout

Comment: ViewHolder class should be static, but I dont think it is the cause of your problem

Comment: Only optimization I can suggest is to use RelativeLayout for your items instead of LinearLayout, besides of that your code seems fine. Which devices have you tested, does all work the same or are you using an emulator. It might be also device related problem.

Comment: After testing on Xolo Q700 and Xperia ,I found this result.

Working well on Xperia L.

In Xolo q700,after i called this function `Debug.startMethodTracing();`.It is working well.Its weird.